# Why does the reputation page say "There were no reputation changes in this day" when the reputation changed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-history

I was looking at the reputation on [this account](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/91/jeff-atwood?tab=reputation&sort=post), and noticed that, while the page shows changes on the reputation, it doesn't give any detail about the reputation change.

[image: screenshot]

For example, on April 28, 2011, the reputation increased by 5, but the note is saying the reputation didn't change. Why does this happen?

Comment: Equally interesting is the fact that the same ummm user only has a total of 93 reputation points at present, whereas, based on the sum from your screenshot, that number should total 137 reputation points.

Comment: You will find evidence of an active user upon perusing http://english.stackexchange.com/users/91/jeff-atwood?tab=activity&sort=comments and more important, **and relevant**  http://english.stackexchange.com/users/91/jeff-atwood?tab=activity&sort=revisions Note that the latter is also **extremely funny**. It provides revealing insights into the sort of um crud that sometimes gets submitted to EL&U, which aforementioned user has confronted.

Comment: Clearly that user is engaging in fraudulent activity and should be banned.

Comment: That's pretty odd.  I wonder if this is somehow related to the fact that we cannot see reputation removed due to deleted posts, but that reputation is not lost if it was 60 days old with at least a score of 3 when it was deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed a bug around posts that satisfy the lived > 60 days and score >= 3 condition (a simple `Posts.DeletionDate Is Not Null` no longer suffices).

It should be resolved in the next build.